# Adding a disk to an Azure VM using PowerShell ARM script

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to add a disk to a VM in Azure using the following PowerShell script:

```
$rgName = "${resourceManager}"
$stName = "${storageAccount}"
$diskname="${diskName}"
$lun = ${lunNum}
$vmName = "${vmName}"
$diskSize=${diskSize}

$storageAcc=Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $stName
$diskpath=$storageAcc.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" +  $diskname  + ".vhd"
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName | Add-AzureRmVMDataDisk -Name $diskname -VhdUri $diskpath -CreateOption empty -DiskSizeInGB $diskSize -Lun $lun
$vm.Tags = $null
$vm | Update-AzureRmVM
```

The following are descriptions of the values I need:

```
SubscriptionID - Azure Subscription ID
AzureUsername - Name of Azure service account. It must be configured as co-administrator on the Azure Subscription
AzurePassword - Associated Azure service account password
resourceManager - Name of Resource Manager (RM) containing the VM
storageAccount - Name of storage account (within the specified RM), where to create the new disk
diskName - desired name of the disk
diskSize - desired size of the disk in Giga Bytes, this is a quota, up to 1000 GB is allowed
lunNum - the lun number to use, valid values are 0,1,2,3, etc.
vmName - the name of an existing VM where to attach the new disk
```

The following are test values I use in the script:

```
SubscriptionID - 06e2bb3d-e66d-4a21-a4a0-78b2fe53f8c6
AzureUsername – test@outlook.com    
AzurePassword – test123
resourceManager – 
storageAccount -
diskName - test
diskSize - 100
lunNum - 
vmName - ALPHABETTVM001
```

I'm unsure where to procure the resourceManager, storageAccount, and lunNum inputs. I'm functionally testing Azure scripts that have been converted from the old ASM to new ARM model, but I don't have a lot of experience with this. Where can I find these three values for my given virtual machine?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.compute/v1.3.4/add-azurermvmdatadisk and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-attach-disk-portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure resource module (ARM, new), we can use Login-AzureRmAccount to login Azure via PowerShell.

> I'm unsure where to procure the resourceManager, storageAccount, and
>   lunNum inputs.

You can login the Azure via PowerShell, and list all the resource group name:
$rgName = "**resource group name**"

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select resourcegroupname
ResourceGroupName
-----------------
Api-Default-North-Central-US
AppResource
CS-WebJobs-NorthCentralUS-scheduler
Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS
Default-Networking
Default-ServiceBus-CentralUS
Default-SQL-CentralUS
Default-Storage-EastUS
Default-Web-NorthCentralUS
DemoVS8172016
DennisSPMonitor
lb1
win
```

Also you can use new portal to find the resource group:
[image]
About **storage account**, we can use PowerShell to list all the storage account in the resource group(also you can find the storage account name via the new portal):

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName win  | select storageaccountname
StorageAccountName
------------------
windiag865  (used for log)
windisks548 (used for data)
```

About **lunnum**, if your VM just have one OS disk without datadisk, the first lunnum is 0 by default, after you add a data disk to the VM, you can use PowerShell to list the Lun number:

```
get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName "win" -Name "win"
StorageProfile             :
  ImageReference           :
    Publisher              : MicrosoftWindowsServer
    Offer                  : WindowsServer
    Sku                    : 2012-R2-Datacenter
    Version                : latest
  OsDisk                   :
    OsType                 : Windows
    Name                   : win
    Vhd                    :
      Uri                  : https://windisks548.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/win20170111102348.vhd
    Caching                : ReadWrite
    CreateOption           : FromImage
  DataDisks[0]             :
    Lun                    : 0
    Name                   : win-20170111-103800
    Vhd                    :
      Uri                  : https://windisks548.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/win-20170111-103800.vhd
    Caching                : None
    CreateOption           : Empty
    DiskSizeGB             : 50
DataDiskNames[0]           : win-20170111-103800

PS > (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName "win" -Name "win").StorageProfile.DataDisks.lun
0
```